# Error object formatting in general

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, error-handling

Main idea is to pass error object from `Model` to `View`.

Simple approach would be to pass just array of errors: `[1,2,6]` or `["missing name", "missing title"]`

But I think someone already could have thought something more smarter. So, is there any standard way of making advanced error objects?

Comment: Have you tryied to use **json** to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Simpler often *is* smarter.

When you're passing errors from the Model (or probably controller) to the View, then all you really want is to tell the user that something's gone wrong, and what to do about it. The only thing I'd consider adding is the id of the field with the issue, so you can highlight it with some css.

I wouldn't try to over complicate this any further.

Depending on the framework you're using you might find there are some helper functions for form inputs built in: angular.js [handles forms very simply](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) for example.

Comment: It is more for development process as standards make life easier for newcomers and they don't need to learn lot of project specific things. But, yes, I am going with your approach, if I won't find any industry standard.